# Admin login from the maintenance page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created an under repair status for my template. My code works correctly without any problems.

My only problem with this code is that if the site administrator activates this code from within the customization and does not deactivate this code after making the desired changes and exits his account, the site will no longer be accessible.

To solve this problem, I want to create a form for the site admin to enter so that he can disable this mode by entering the WordPress settings.

According to the edits I made for my question and with the help of **Script Host**, I reached the following code:

```
function custom_maintenance_mode_page() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_themes' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $text = 'The site is being updated. please wait.';
        $text2 = 'To deactivate, please enter your email and password (the email and password of the site administrator)';

        echo '<html>';
        echo '<body>';
        echo '<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:100px;">';
        echo '<p class="txt-edit_themes">' . esc_html( $text ) . '</p>';
        echo '<p class="txt-edit_themes">' . esc_html( $text2 ) . '</p>';
        
        echo '<form method="post" action="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>" class="input-group">';
        echo '<p><input type="text" name="log" id="user_Login" placeholder="Email or username"></p>';
        echo '<p><input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_Pass" placeholder="Password"></p>';
        echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>';
         echo '</form>';
        
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</body>';
        echo '</html>';
        die();
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $email = $_POST['user_Login'];
        $password = $_POST['user_Pass'];

        $user = wp_get_user_by( 'email', $email );

        if ( $user && $user->user_pass === $password ) {
            // Redirect to the WordPress settings page
            wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=site-maintenance' ) );
            die();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'custom_maintenance_mode_page' );
```

By entering the details of the site administrator, I am transferred to the **403 page**, which tells me that you do not have permission to access this part.

It also shows me such an address in the URL:

```
http://localhost/site/<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>
```

path `<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>` in the form tag and in the action section, it displays what I have used.

I made the following changes to the WordPress login page:

```
function woo_register_user( $email, $first_name, $last_name, $pass1, $pass2 ) {
  $errors = new WP_Error();
  if ( username_exists( $username ) || email_exists( $username ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'username_exists', 'username_exists' );
    return $errors;
  }

  if ( !is_email( $email ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'email', 'email' );
    return $errors;
  }
  if ( empty( $pass1 ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'password_empty', 'password_empty' );
    return $errors;
  }
  if ( $pass1 != $pass2 ) {
    $errors->add( 'password_mismatch', 'password_mismatch' );
    return $errors;
  }
  $user_data = array(
    'user_email' => $email,
    'user_pass' => $pass1,
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'user_login' => $username,
    'nickname' => $username,
  );
  $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
  wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $pass1 );
  return $user_id;
}
```

I already searched to find a similar topic with this general problem but couldn't find anything.

I just want the site admin to be allowed to enter the WordPress settings through the maintenance page, and there is no such access for other users.

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

**Edit:**

With a recent edit made with the help of Script Host, the maintenance page code is completely disabled.

But this was not what I wanted.

The maintenance section should remain and only allow the site administrator to access the settings.

Edited code:

```
function after_setup_theme() {
    
    // Add the maintenance mode page
add_action( 'get_header', 'custom_maintenance_mode_page' );

// Add the code to disable maintenance mode
add_action( 'init', 'disable_maintenance_mode' );

}



function custom_maintenance_mode_page() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_themes' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ) {
$text = 'The site is being updated. please wait.';
$text2 = 'To deactivate, please enter your email and password (the email and password of the site administrator)';

echo '<html>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:100px;">';
echo '<p class="txt-edit_themes">' . esc_html( $text ) . '</p>';
echo '<p class="txt-edit_themes">' . esc_html( $text2 ) . '</p>';

echo '<form method="post" action="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>" class="input-group">';
echo '<p><input type="text" name="log" id="user_Login" placeholder="Email or username"></p>';
echo '<p><input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_Pass" placeholder="Password"></p>';
echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>';
echo '</form>';

echo '</div>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
}
}

function disable_maintenance_mode() {
if ( isset( $_POST['user_Login'] ) && isset( $_POST['user_Pass'] ) ) {
$email = $_POST['user_Login'];
$password = $_POST['user_Pass'];

// Get the user ID of the site administrator
$user_id = get_option('admin_email');

// Check if the email and password are correct
$user = wp_authenticate( $email, $password );

if ( $user && $user->ID == $user_id ) {
// Disable the maintenance mode
wp_maintenance_mode( false );

// Redirect to the front page
wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how this could work. This code allows the user to log in and checks whether it has the necessary permissions to disable repair mode. If they do, it will disable the repair mode (as a plugin) and redirect the user to the homepage.

```
function custom_maintenance_mode_page() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit_deactivate'])) {
        $user_login = $_POST['log'];
        $user_pass = $_POST['pwd'];
        $creds = array(
            'user_login'    => $user_login,
            'user_password' => $user_pass,
            'remember'      => false
        );
        $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
        if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
            $error = $user->get_error_message();
        } else {
            if (current_user_can( 'edit_themes' )) {
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
                $plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
                deactivate_plugins( $plugin );
                wp_redirect( home_url() );
                exit;
            } else {
                $error = 'You do not have permission to deactivate repair mode.';
            }
        }
    }

    if ( (!current_user_can( 'edit_themes' ) || !is_user_logged_in()) ) {
        $text = 'The site is being updated. please wait.'; 
        $text2 = 'To deactivate, please enter your email and password (the email and password of the site administrator)';
        ?>

        <html>
            <body>
                <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:100px;">
                    <p class="txt-edit_themes"><?php echo esc_html( $text )?></p>
                    <p class="txt-edit_themes"><?php echo esc_html( $text2 )?></p>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($error)) {
                        echo '<p class="error-edit_themes">' . $error . '</p>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" method="post">
                        <p><input class="login-user-log-field" type="text" name="log" id="user_Login" placeholder="Email or username"></p>
                        <p><input class="login-user-log-field" type="password" name="pwd" id="user_Pass" placeholder="Password"></p>
                        <p><input id="login-user-log_submit" type="submit" name="submit_deactivate" value="To deactivate"></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
        <?php
        die(); 
    }
}
add_action( 'get_headers', 'custom_maintenance_mode_page' );
```

Comment: Hello. I apologize for my late reply. I do not use any plugins and I have designed the WordPress login page so that users do not have access to WordPress settings and are redirected to the page I designed for users. For the repair mode, I have only put this code in the **functions.php** file. Now I want only the general manager (admin) or the person who started the site to be able to **disable** the repair mode or connect to the **WordPress** **settings** panel by entering the user name or email as well as the password. I have already explained the reason for this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please, if it is possible, I would be grateful if you could complete this code for me.